# Classify Types in Boost Variant using Visitor does not compile

Tags: c++, templates, generics, boost-mpl, boost-variant

I'm using `boost-variant` throughout my projects. In one scenario I need to classify the types contained in my `boost-variant` into several classes. As I have quite a lot of types in my variant I came up to the idea of defining several variants inside my visitor. These variants are basically the type->class mapping.

The code below illustrates what I wanted to achieve.

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <boost/variant.hpp>
    #include <string>

    enum class Type {
        Integer,
        Float,
        NonNumeric
    };

    struct IsNum : public boost::static_visitor<Type> {
        typedef boost::variant<int, size_t> IntegerTypes;
        typedef boost::variant<float, double> FloatTypes;
        typedef boost::variant<std::string> NonNumericTypes;

        result_type operator()(const IntegerTypes& t) const {
            return Type::Integer;
        }

        result_type operator()(const FloatTypes& t) const {
            return Type::Float;
        }

        result_type operator()(const NonNumericTypes& t) const {
            return Type::NonNumeric;
        }
    };

    int main() {
        boost::variant<int, std::string, double> value;
        value = 5;
        IsNum visitor;
        auto result = value.apply_visitor(visitor);
    }
```

Unfortunately, the code will not compile. MSVC ends with the compiler error `C3066`. There are different possibilities to call an object of this type with this arguments? It might be one of the three `operator()` functions.

But basically I can convert 5 only to the variant type `IntegerTypes`.

What might be the solution for this kind of problem?

**Own Solution**

After trying to use `boost-mpl` I arrived at this solution. The function `Contains` represents a piece of reusable software, that might be included into other pieces of my program. Still I wished the solution would be closer to my original posted source code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/variant.hpp>
#include <string>
#include <boost/mpl/contains.hpp>

enum class Type {
    Integer,
    Float,
    NonNumeric
};

template<typename V, typename T>
using ContainsImpl = typename boost::mpl::contains<typename V::types, T>::type;

template<typename V, typename T>
bool Contains(const T&) {
    return ContainsImpl<V, T>::value;
}

struct IsNum : public boost::static_visitor<Type> {
    typedef boost::variant<int, size_t> IntegerTypes;
    typedef boost::variant<float, double> FloatTypes;
    typedef boost::variant<std::string> NonNumericTypes;

    template<typename T>
    result_type operator()(const T& t) const {
        if (Contains<IntegerTypes>(t)) {
            return Type::Integer;
        } else if (Contains<FloatTypes>(t)) {
            return Type::Float;
        } else if (Contains<NonNumericTypes>(t)) {
            return Type::NonNumeric;
        }

        return Type::NonNumeric;
    }
};

int main() {
    boost::variant<int, std::string, double> value;
    value = 5.;
    IsNum visitor;
    auto result = value.apply_visitor(visitor);
    if (result == Type::Integer) {
        std::cout << "Integer" << std::endl;
    }
    if (result == Type::Float) {
        std::cout << "Float" << std::endl;
    } 
    if (result == Type::NonNumeric) {
        std::cout << "Non Numeric" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#include <string>
#include <boost/variant.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/list.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/contains.hpp>
#include <boost/type_traits.hpp>

enum class Type
{
    Integer,
    Float,
    NonNumeric
};

struct IsNum : public boost::static_visitor<Type>
{
    typedef boost::mpl::list<int, size_t> IntegerTypes;
    typedef boost::mpl::list<float, double> FloatTypes;
    typedef boost::mpl::list<std::string> NonNumericTypes;

    template <typename T>
    typename boost::enable_if<boost::mpl::contains<IntegerTypes, T>, result_type>::type
    operator()(const T& t) const
    {
        return Type::Integer;
    }

    template <typename T>
    typename boost::enable_if<boost::mpl::contains<FloatTypes, T>, result_type>::type
    operator()(const T& t) const
    {
        return Type::Float;
    }

    template <typename T>
    typename boost::enable_if<boost::mpl::contains<NonNumericTypes, T>, result_type>::type
    operator()(const T& t) const
    {
        return Type::NonNumeric;
    }
};
```

[**DEMO**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6795e28d17ccbe95)

Comment: Cool. I also derived this solution now. It seems to be the only workable approach. But reading it might get you headache. :-) I'll post my solution also. Many thanks.

Comment: @FrankSimon more alternatives include: tag-dispatching and adding a separate overload for each type

Comment: No idea what tag-dispatching is. I'll think that I have to learn a bit more. :-)